# How to access SharePoint online data in plain html page using Javascript ? [External page]

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api

How to access SharePoint online data in plain html page using Javascript ? [External page]

Is it possible? I tried using STS but not getting the proper result !

Followed these links -

- [Accessing Office 365 SharePoint Sites Using REST From A Local HTML / JavaScript Host](https://pholpar.wordpress.com/2013/05/11/accessing-office-365-sharepoint-sites-using-rest-from-a-local-html-javascript-host/)
- [SharePoint Online Authentication via JavaScript](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/SharePoint-Online-d9fdb136#content)

Answer (score 1):

You can create the Web Service using [SharePoint Client Object Model](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/complete-basic-operations-using-sharepoint-client-library-code) which will returns SharePoint Online Data.

Then, you can call that Web Service from your html page using JavaScript.